# Cannot deserialise the JSON array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working with VB.Net and can't manage to display the following JSON file in a datagridview.

```
{"files":[
{"file": "Test.out", "linecount": "4"},{"file": "test1.out", "linecount": "41"},{"file": "NocheinTest.out", "linecount": "41"}
]}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please update your post to include what you have tried to resolve your issue, what isn't working and expected output.

Comment: A possible way: `dim files = JObject.Parse(Json)("files").ToDictionary(function(jt) jt("file").ToString(), function(jt) Convert.ToInt32(jt("linecount"))) dataGridView1.DataSource = files.ToList()`. Otherwise, build a class model. Visual Studio  has a dedicated tool, `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as classes`. Many online sources, for example: [JsonUtils.com](https://jsonutils.com/) offers the VB.Net language option.

Comment: This, of course, if you're using the Newtonsoft.Json library ([Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

Comment: Where are you getting an error? You didn't post any code.

Comment: wow it works . thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the complete code

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim url As String
    url = "http://...."
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim s As String
    s = reader.ReadToEnd


    Dim files = JObject.Parse(s)("files").ToDictionary(Function(jt) jt("file").ToString(), Function(jt) Convert.ToInt32(jt("linecount")))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = files.ToList()
```